# Pass ID of current record to Apex Controller

Tags: visualforce

I'm working on a Visualforce Email Template which will be sent from the parent **Loan** (`LLC_BI__Loan__c`) record in Salesforce, and I'm trying to include fields from the child **Entity Involvement** (`LLC_BI__Legal_Entities__c`) record(s).

I'm attempting to pass the Loan record ID into the Controller using the ApexPages.StandardSetController method, but I think it may be failing due to the fact that the Visualforce component is being used in the email template and not on a record page.

I'm unable to pass the correct parent (Loan) Id to get the correct child records. Can anyone see where I may be going wrong ?

Thank you in advance.

Component:

'
    
        
            
                    Borrower Name
                {!borrower.LLC_BI__Borrower_Type__c}
            
        
'

Controller:

```
public class BorrowersOnLoans { 
public Id loanId {get;set;}
private final LLC_BI__Loan__c loan;
    public BorrowersOnLoans (ApexPages.StandardSetController controller) {
        loan = (LLC_BI__Loan__c) controller.getRecord();
    }
    public List<LLC_BI__Legal_Entities__c> getrelatedBorrowers()
    {
        List <LLC_BI__Legal_Entities__c> conList = New List<LLC_BI__Legal_Entities__c>();
        for(LLC_BI__Loan__c ln:
        [SELECT id,name, (SELECT id, LLC_BI__Borrower_Type__c, LLC_BI__Account__r.Name FROM LLC_BI__Legal_Entities__r) FROM LLC_BI__Loan__c WHERE id = :loanId])
        {
           for(LLC_BI__Legal_Entities__c con:ln.LLC_BI__Legal_Entities__r)
               conList.add(con);
        }
        return conList;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thinking that you don't need "loan" or "loan=..." in the BorrowersOnLoans constructor (you aren't using it anywhere).
And, how are you using the component (are you passing currentRecordId parameter correctly to the component)?

Comment: Thanks @Paul N

I removed "loan" from constructor, but I think I must still be setting the loanId incorrectly. When I I hard-code a Loan record ID in my query, and then run the VF Template from that Loan record, it doesn't pull in any field values from the child records - and I've tried it on different records.

Here is what I have for my Apex class now:

Comment: public class BorrowersOnLoans { 

    public Id loanId { get; set { loanId = value; loadChildren(); } } 
    public LLC_BI__Legal_Entities__c[] relatedBorrowers { get; set; } 
    void loadChildren() 
{ 

List <LLC_BI__Legal_Entities__c> entList = new List<LLC_BI__Legal_Entities__c>(); 

for(LLC_BI__Loan__c loan: 

[SELECT id, name, (SELECT id, Entity_Name__c FROM LLC_BI__Legal_Entities__r) FROM LLC_BI__Loan__c WHERE id = :loanId])

 {
 
 for(LLC_BI__Legal_Entities__c ent:loan.LLC_BI__Legal_Entities__r) entList.add(ent); 
 
 }
     }
         }

Comment: ...and the Component:


<apex:component controller="BorrowersOnLoans" access="global">
    <apex:attribute name="currentRecordId" description="" assignTo="{!loanId}" type="Id"/>
        <apex:dataTable value="{!relatedBorrowers}" var="borrower">
            <apex:column >
                    <apex:facet name="header">Borrower Name</apex:facet>
                {!borrower.Entity_Name__c}
            </apex:column>
        </apex:dataTable>
</apex:component>

Comment: Email Template:

<c:BorrowerRecordsFromLoans currentRecordId="{!relatedTo.Id}"/>

Answer (score 6):

As long as you set the loanId correctly, the children should load just fine. The ApexPages.StandardSetController constructor won't be called, but it shouldn't matter. As a practical matter, the only change I'd make is to load the records when the loanId is set:

```
public class BorrowersOnLoans { 
  public Id loanId { get; set { loanId = value; loadChildren(); } }
  public LLC_BI__Loan__c[] relatedBorrowers { get; set; }
  void loadChildren() {
      // do your queries and stuff here //
  }
}
```

Make sure the template provides the ID:

```
<c:borrowers currentRecordId="{!relatedTo.Id}" />
```

And, finally, make sure the class name matches the controller on the component. This might just be a typo in your post, but obviously using the wrong class would be a problem.

Comment: Thank you sfdcfox - you're correct, I did have the wrong class name in my Component.

Comment: Here is what I have now...I'm obviously missing something because it's still not working. Any Ideas ?

Comment: Controller:public class BorrowersOnLoans { 
    public String conList { get; set; }
  public Id loanId { get; set { loanId = value; loadChildren(); } }
  public LLC_BI__Loan__c[] relatedBorrowers { get; set; }
  void loadChildren() {
        List <LLC_BI__Legal_Entities__c> conList = New List<LLC_BI__Legal_Entities__c>();
        for(LLC_BI__Loan__c loan:
 [SELECT name, (SELECT Entity_Name__c FROM LLC_BI__Legal_Entities__r) FROM LLC_BI__Loan__c WHERE id = :loanid])
        { for(LLC_BI__Legal_Entities__c con:loan.LLC_BI__Legal_Entities__r)
               conList.add(con);
        }}}

Comment: Component:<apex:component controller="BorrowersOnLoans" access="global">
    <apex:attribute name="currentRecordId" description="" assignTo="{!loanId}" type="Id"/>
        <apex:dataTable value="{!conList}" var="borrower">
            <apex:column >
                    <apex:facet name="header">Borrower Name</apex:facet>
                {!borrower.Entity_Name__c}
            </apex:column>
        </apex:dataTable>
</apex:component>

Comment: Email Template:

<c:BorrowerRecordsFromLoans currentRecordId="{!relatedTo.Id}"/>


*I'm getting an error when I try to save the Component:
 Error: Unknown property 'String.Entity_Name__c' 
I had created a formula field on the 'Entity Involvement' object so I wouldn't have to traverse through the Account object to get the Name


Thank you

Comment: @Silver2019 conList is a String at the class level. It should be a `List<LLC_BI_Legal_Entities__c>`, presumably. Also, the local variable by the same name needs to be removed.

Comment: Controller:

public class BorrowersOnLoans { 

    public Id loanId { get; set { loanId = value; loadChildren(); } } 
    public LLC_BI__Legal_Entities__c[] relatedBorrowers { get; set; } 
    void loadChildren() 
{ 
List <LLC_BI__Legal_Entities__c> entList = new List<LLC_BI__Legal_Entities__c>(); 

for(LLC_BI__Loan__c loan: 

[SELECT Id, (SELECT Entity_Name__c FROM LLC_BI__Legal_Entities__r ORDER BY Borrower_Number__c) FROM LLC_BI__Loan__c WHERE Id = :loanId])

 {
 
 for(LLC_BI__Legal_Entities__c ent:loan.LLC_BI__Legal_Entities__r) entList.add(ent); 
 
 }
     }
         }

Comment: Component:

<apex:component controller="BorrowersOnLoans" access="global">
    <apex:attribute name="currentRecordId" description="" assignTo="{!loanId}" type="Id"/>
        <apex:dataTable value="{!relatedBorrowers}" var="borrower">
            <apex:column >
                    <apex:facet name="header">Borrower Name</apex:facet>
                {!borrower.LLC_BI__Borrower_Type__c}
            </apex:column>
        </apex:dataTable>
</apex:component>

Comment: I'm still not getting anything when I run the template (and thank you very kindly for your help thus far).

Comment: @Silver2019 Can you edit that code in to your question? It's hard to read them as comments.

Comment: It only lets me use 500 characters in the Comment so I had to take out some blank spaces

Comment: If it helps, I edited this post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59502890/pass-id-of-current-record-to-apex-controller) to include the current code I'm using.